# CUITe test execution fails under VS2015

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests, cuite

Using [CUITe](https://cuite.codeplex.com/) testing framework in VS2012, I created a coded UI test.  This test works as expected when right clicking the test, and hitting "run test" in VS2012.

We are in the process of migrating to VS2015, so I'm trying to go through our solutions to make sure they are behaving as expected.  In this solutions case, we are running into an issue where when attempting to run a test, the output pane states:

> There is no test with the specified Id (guid listed)

And no CUITe tests are run.

I have confirmed that normal coded UI tests are running in VS2015, it is specifically coded UI tests created using CUITe that are failing to run.

Don't know if anyone will have any workarounds for this, but I figured I'd give it a shot.  I have additionally added all of the "Microsoft Testing" dlls to the solution in a separate folder, in order to ensure the solution is using the "specific versions" of the testing DLLs.  This did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to CUITe not having been compiled/provided a build definition for VS2015.

In the current GitHub repo of CUITe (code plex URL from the original question no longer the "active link") provides a new build that addresses the issue.

Current URL for CUITe is: 
https://github.com/icnocop/cuite

Issue was resolved [here](https://github.com/icnocop/cuite/issues/30).